# Diferencias load, get o post entre jquery 1.8.3 y 1.12.4

Tags: jquery, post, get

gente! Buenos días, buenas tardes;
Soy nuevo en la comunidad aunque generalmente entro a buscar información y lo consigo con la busqueda, pero esta vez es diferente. Les cuento el caso porque quizás me puedan ayudar.
Estoy haciendo un visualizador de archivos y carpetas en PHP, quiero que al entrar a una carpeta(hacer clic en ella) se actualice el contenido del div en donde estan las carpetas y archivos. Utilicé jquery para eso y leí que load está obsoleto en las ultimas versiones de jquery (de 1.8 en adelante) por lo que recomiendan get o post. Por ese motivo utilicé jquery 1.12.4 e hice que mi aplicación funcionara (2 veces).....
Es decir si hago click para entrar a una carpeta funciona bien, si entro a otra o vuelvo a la carpeta padre funciona pero si hago clic una tercera vez no tengo más suerte.... Me hice chichones buscando la solución hasta que decidí probar con la versión 1.8.3 y al usar esa versión funciona sin problemas... Lo efectivo sería dejar esa y seguir con otra cosa pero mi idea es incluir eso como un plugin de wordpress y voy a tener versiones de jquery más nuevas y posiblemente me generen problemas.... Pongo aquí el codigo de jquery que uso.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Carpetas li").click(function() {
            //alert (this.id);
            $.get("http://direccionsitio.com/filemanager/prueba3.php", {dir: this.id}, function(htmlexterno){
                $(".container").html(htmlexterno);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí estas modificando el **.container** que tiene el listado de carpeta, puede que los eventos del click no funcione porque lo elimina, una opción sería usar **on** de **jQuery**:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Esto te permite mantener el evento vivo aunque se elimine el elemento del **DOM**. Sí no quieres usar **on** puede realizar el siguiente código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var EventoClick = function() {
        $("#Carpetas li").unbind('click');
        $("#Carpetas li").click(function() {
            //alert (this.id);
            $.get("http://direccionsitio.com/filemanager/prueba3.php", {dir: this.id}, function(htmlexterno){
                $(".container").html(htmlexterno);
                EventoClick();
            });
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){
        EventoClick();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Excelente! Funcionó sin problemas!! Es eso, lei un poco la documentación de la función on y vi como live se usaba antes y ahora recomiendan on. Pero la duda que me surge es porque con la versión más nueva de jquery no funciona? ¿ Es porque era sintacticamente incorrecto lo que escribí y se dejó de ser "flexible" con esta forma de escribir el código?. Muchas gracias por la solución!!!